# Tool Convert XSLT Big file XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that's approximately 200MB. It may not be that big, but almost every program has trouble handling it.

I am looking for a program to open this XML file, then add XSLT code and generate the converted XML file.

I've tried XML Oxyged Editor, but after opening the file, it is too big and the program crashes.

To read the XML I first used Object XML Editor. This program reads this file with no problem, but when I try transform I get runtime error.

I am looking for a solution for 2 days now, please help.

Comment: 200 MB doesn't sound like too big to be handled by conventional editors or conventional XSLT (i.e. 1.0 or 2.0) processing. For XSLT 3, there is a new option to do streamed, forwards only, processing, not building the full tree. But it requires Saxon EE, for which you need at least an evaluation license. As for oXygen, configure is memory use and note that under Tools it has a "large file viewer". oXygen also comes bundled with Saxon EE so there XSLT 3 with streaming can be an option.

Comment: Other options for big XML files are XML databases like BaseX or eXist-db.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for your reply. Now  I found solution and transform xml with xslt using oXygen without need open to read xml  file ;))

Comment: Asking recommendations of software/libraries/tools is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow as it can lead to spam or opinionated answers. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) on your own for an implementation and then ask about issues with your earnest attempt.